# Can i declare two IDD in one project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am using two classes in one project. First class is `CClientSocketDlg` and other one is `CUserSpecificationDlg`.

Here is the some part of the code.

```
class CClientSocketDlg : public CDialog
{
  public:
    bool StartClient();
    CClientSocketDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);
    void AppendMessage(LPCTSTR strText );

    enum { IDD = IDD_CLIENTSOCKET_DIALOG };
    CEdit   m_ctlMsgList;
    CIPAddressCtrl  m_ctlIPAddress;
};

class CuserspecificationDlg : public CDialogEx
{
  public:
    CuserspecificationDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);

    // Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_USERSPECIFICATION_DIALOG };
    CListCtrl m_List;
    CString out;  // For Edit control in list box having IDC_EDIT2
  protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
};
```

Can I declare them in one project ? Is it allowed? Can I use `m_ctlIPAddress`
in CUserspecification class ?

Comment: You can do that. What is the problem? Do you think a project allow only one dialog in it :)?

Comment: Actually m_ctlIPAddress is defined in the function under CCLIENTSOCKET DLG class ad it has its own dodataexchage (). So this m_ctlIPAddress can't be properly initialized from UserspecificationDlg class.

Comment: That's why every dialog needs its own DoDataExchange override.

Comment: yeah, i need to initalize Userspecification dialog only , in which clientDLGfunctionality can be call. So how to use dodataexchange of CLIENTDLG in userspecDLG. ?